# Is there any color sensor that reads R,G,B and Clear channel values in parallel?

Tags: sensor, photodiode

Currently, I'm using a color sensor TCS3200 it has 8x8 photodiode array, of which 16 are RED filtered, 16 are Green filtered,16 are Blue and 16 are clear. I can read one color channel at a time i.e. if I'm reading RED I cannot read other three channel i.e. Green, Blue, and Clear of the above-given sensor. The sensor I'm looking for is that reads all 4 channels in parallel. I looked at some CMOS camera sensor modules like OV7670 but it does not run faster than 30fps and I don't need that kind of resolution either.
For my application, I need the sensor to be able to read values at a minimum rate of 120 fps.
So I wanna know is there any sensor that achieves parallel RGBC channel reading.
Note- My application is color sensing, not imaging

Comment: Three TCS3200's?

Comment: 4 channel analog?

Answer (score 1):

With S0 and S1 high the datasheet says the photodiode can run at 500-600kHz so I doubt your sensor is the problem. The Arduino is probably the limiting factor (I'm implying that's what you're using because of your tags). Have you changed the fuses to run the Arduino at 8Mhz instead of the default 1Mhz? If not that should give you the speed bump you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, You are right about the frequency. Actually, I am trying to sense color 15-25 cm far away from the sensor, so I used a lens which is resulting in light intensity loss thus reducing my frequency output. I will find a better lens that does not result in light intensity loss. Thank you.